# Как осуществить динамическое обноление меню?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть два меню, одно для авторизированных пользователей, второе нет. Сейчас это сделано так:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_after_auth, menu);
    } else {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_before_auth, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Но срабатывает этот метод только один раз, при создании активити, если в процессе работы пользователь разлогинится меню не перестраиваться. Как сделать чтобы оно изменялось сразу же после изменения статуса юзера?

ЗЫ Я понимаю что в onCreate есть слушатель, который может реагировать на все это

```
mAuthList = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                Log.d("TAG", "user signed in");
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "user NOT signed in");
            }
        }
    };
```

Но что в нем нужно сделать все равно никак не соображу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) - он приведёт к повторному вызову `onCreateOptionsMenu` и, соответственно меню обновится:

```
 mAuthList = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};
```